# Apollo server : Mutation returns: Models.create(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, apollo

I'm coding an Apollo server.
The Query work very well but when I'm trying to make a mutation it returns the Models.create(...).exec() is not a function. The new data I pass in gets created.
I've been trying to fix it for hours, and I don't know where I'm doing wrong
Here is my resolver

```
    const  { Models }  = require('./dataSource/models')
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        getPerson: async (_, args) => {
            let response = await Models.find(args)
            return response
        }
    },
    Mutation: {
        addPerson: async (_, args) => {
            try{     
            let response = await Models.create(args).exec()
                 return response
                }
                 catch(err){
                     return console.log(err)
                 }
        }
    }
}
module.exports = resolvers
```

and Here the model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;

const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    gender: String,
    age: Number
});

const Models = model('person', PersonSchema)

module.exports = { Models }
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: check what `await Models.create(args)` returns, because whatever it is returning does not have `exec()` method on it

Comment: Thank you, I just removed the exec() function and it's running. It's the first time I use mongoose and I thought  we need to execute it to get created at the server. Thank you